# Can I run my HP ProBook 4230s laptop without the wireless card in the slot?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop

I am having problems with the built-in wireless card. At the moment, I can’t even boot the laptop—an [HP ProBook 4230s](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04287316)—because it says error 104: unsupported wireless network device detected, so I opened the laptop and removed the wireless card. Now I’m wondering, can I just put back everything and try to turn on the laptop again? I’m a bit scared because of the two antennas that won’t be connected to anything.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I’m wondering, can I just put back everything and try to turn on
>   the laptop again?

You should be able to run the system without a component like that installed. As far as the computer is considered, a device like that is a PCI card and a non-critical component that either exists or doesn’t.

That said, you say this:

> I’m a bit scared because of the two antennas that won’t be connected
>   to anything.

Unsure of how the HP ProBook 4230s is setup but in general, the antennas are just pieces of wire. If they are not connected to anything, then they won’t matter. But you should make sure those wires are not just floating in there hanging over—or near—other components. Or else you run the risk of accidentally shorting something out in the machine.

All that said, [looking at this video on YouTube on how to remove the Wi-Fi card from a HP ProBook 4230s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcZp_d8iShc) shows the two antenna connectors don’t *seem* to be floating near anything when the Wi-Fi card installed:

[image]

But this shot *does* show some bare components nearby when the Wi-Fi card is completely removed:

[image]

So if you are a bit nervous, it might be best to just invest in some small pieces of tape to secure the antenna connectors somewhere safe in the machine’s case so they don’t dangle around randomly. But I generally would not worry about unused antennas—in and of themselves—simply being disconnected in a computer case. They are just wires and are not really critical to a system running.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see any problems with that. You might want to wrap the antenna connectors in tape or even tape them down somewhere so they don’t touch any circuitry. Other than that, there shouldn’t be any problems.